# Titanium - creating a single column picker with data from json

Tags: xml, json, titanium, picker

I am trying to create a single column picker whose data is derived from a json doc. Right now i am coding for an iOS device, but plan to use same code for android. When i run this code, the picker is empty. Any help is appreciated!

```
////
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title:"Creating a Single-Column Picker",
    backgroundColor:"#FFF",
    exitOnClose:true
});

var url ="http://stats.catchitkansas.com/sunflower/cik/xml/app/app_master_schools.json"; //  rss     feed url

var json, object_name, locatie, i, row, title, val;

//A single column picker

var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
bottom:0,
});

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({ 

    onload: function(e) { // Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);

        json = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
            for (i = 0; i < json.object_name.length; i++) { 

            locatie = json.object_name[i]; 

            picker.add(Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title: e.locatie.title}));
            }   
        //Now, we need add the pickerRow objects in the data array to the picker
        Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);
        alert('success');

        }, 
    }

);
picker.selectionIndicator = true;

xhr.open('GET',url);

xhr.send();

//This label contains text that will change with each picker change
var results = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:"Select from the picker below",
    height:40,
    width:"auto",
    top:20  
});

//When using a picker, listen for the "change" event
picker.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    results.text = e.row.title + ": " + e.row.val; //Pull the title and val properties from the     selected pickerRow object (accessed via e.row)
});

win.add(picker);
win.add(results);

win.open();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue #1

Your data feed is returning improperly formatted JSON.

Change this

`"object_name": {`

to

`"object_name":`

(Found by running the JSON through http://jsonlint.com/)

---

#### Issue #2

Change this

`picker.add(Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title: e.locatie.title}));`

to

`picker.add(Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title: locatie.title}));`

The `locatie` object isn't part of the event variable `e`, it's a stand-alone variable.

---

#### Issue #3

The picker is being added *before* the HttpClient request is finished.

You should move `win.add(picker);` to just after the `for` loop inside the `onload` callback.

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({ 
    onload: function(e) { 
        json = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 

        for (i = 0; i < json.object_name.length; i++) { 
            locatie = json.object_name[i];

            picker.add(Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title: locatie.title}));
        }   

        win.add(picker);
        alert('success');
    } 
});
```

Comment: I'm assuming the picker still isn't displaying anything. Can you update the original source to show the correct feed?

Comment: Source has been updated. And the picker still isn't showing the info. But thank you for pointing in the right direction with the JSON. I wasn't sure about that to begin with.

Comment: THANK YOU MARK! You rock! Works like a champ.